# Wired connection setting

Tags: networking

my Internet connection is 10baseT-HD, in order to surfing the network, I have to type the command "mii-tool -F 10baseT-HD" every booting. How can I make it auto-setting?

Comment: which version of ubuntu and what desktop?  Do you want to run this on login or when the machine is booting?  Does mii-tool ask for an administrator password to run or does it run with the credentials of the user logged on.

Comment: um, ubuntu 11.10, unity desktop. and I just want it run when the pc is booting. Running the mii-tool must need the root permission; otherwise, it displays "no MII interfaces found".

Comment: I dont have any experience with mii-tool - however this link looks promising.  Let us know what you find out:  http://mouweb.com/2011/02/28/set-speed-and-duplexing-on-ubuntu-debian/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add  `mii-tool -F 10baseT-HD` to `/etc/rc.local` (before the `exit 0`) and then save it.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried the following:

1. Go To System Settings
2. Select Network under Hardware
3. Select configure on your connection
4. Select IPv4 Settings tab
5. Ensure Method is set to Automatic (DHCP)
6. Select Save
7. Select IPv6 Settings tab
8. Ensure Method is set to Automatic
9. Select Save

I would suggest restarting your system...hopefully this will automatically detect and connect your Internet!  Good Luck!

Comment: all of your suggestions were done, but it doesn't work better at all...